# Malware - Technical anlaysis

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, malware, debug, wireshark

**Note: Please do not mod down or close. Im not a stupid PC user asking to fix my pc problem. I am intrigued and am having a deep technical look at whats going on.**

I have come across a Windows XP machine that is sending unwanted p2p traffic.

I have done a 'netstat -b' command and explorer.exe is sending out the traffic. When I kill this process the traffic stops and obviously Windows Explorer dies.

Here is the header of the stream from the Wireshark dump (x.x.x.x) is the machines IP.

```
GNUTELLA CONNECT/0.6
Listen-IP: x.x.x.x:8059
Remote-IP: 76.164.224.103
User-Agent: LimeWire/5.3.6
X-Requeries: false
X-Ultrapeer: True
X-Degree: 32
X-Query-Routing: 0.1
X-Ultrapeer-Query-Routing: 0.1
X-Max-TTL: 3
X-Dynamic-Querying: 0.1
X-Locale-Pref: en
GGEP: 0.5
Bye-Packet: 0.1

GNUTELLA/0.6 200 OK
Pong-Caching: 0.1
X-Ultrapeer-Needed: false
Accept-Encoding: deflate
X-Requeries: false
X-Locale-Pref: en
X-Guess: 0.1
X-Max-TTL: 3
Vendor-Message: 0.2
X-Ultrapeer-Query-Routing: 0.1
X-Query-Routing: 0.1
Listen-IP: 76.164.224.103:15649
X-Ext-Probes: 0.1
Remote-IP: x.x.x.x
GGEP: 0.5
X-Dynamic-Querying: 0.1
X-Degree: 32
User-Agent: LimeWire/4.18.7
X-Ultrapeer: True
X-Try-Ultrapeers: 121.54.32.36:3279,173.19.233.80:3714,65.182.97.15:5807,115.147.231.81:9751,72.134.30.181:15810,71.59.97.180:24295,74.76.84.250:25497,96.234.62.221:32344,69.44.246.38:42254,98.199.75.23:51230

GNUTELLA/0.6 200 OK
```

So it seems that the malware has hooked into explorer.exe and hidden its self quite well as a Norton Scan doesn't pick anything up.

I have looked in Windows firewall and it shouldn't be letting this traffic through.

I have had a look into the messages explorer.exe is sending in Spy++ and the only related ones I can see are socket connections etc...

My question is what can I do to look into this deeper? 
What does malware achieve by sending p2p traffic?

I know to fix the problem the easiest way is to reinstall Windows but I want to get to the bottom of it first, just out of interest.

**Edit:**

Had a look at Deoendency Walker and Process Explorer.

Both great tools. Here is a image of the TCP connections for explorer.exe in Process Explorer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that the trojan is using the p2p network as a command and control channel.
since p2p is all about distribution, there is no single point that can be shut down to take down the the botnet.

what you are seeing is probably your pet bot looking for orders.

one idea to look further is to run [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on explore.exe to see what dlls it pulls in, one of them may be the bot.

Answer (score 1):

The malware is probably hooking itself onto explorer.exe.

Try using Sysinternals' Processexplorer to find out more:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Sysinternals also has a rootkitscanner which locates hidden files/registry entries.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to exterminate the malware and I think that it was successful.

Please search for `C:\Windows\halperf10.exe` or any `.exe` file with a comparatively new time stamp similar to it.